# How to programmatically change style sheet of buttons in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

I have so many buttons on a dialog and I want to change style sheets of them under some conditions.
Button object names are like below:

btn_1

btn_2

btn_3

..

btn_20

When I clicked one of these numerical buttons and later to another simple button, I want to change first clicked numerical button style sheet. How can I access that selected numerical button?

Edit:
What I mean by picture

[image: buttons]

I am trying to set colors of left column buttons (has numerically ordered object names) with right column buttons. User will be clicked numerical buttons first and then color named buttons.

Comment: the graphic helps you to understand your goal in part but you could better explain to you when the color should be established. For example, if you press the btn_4 button and then the Red button I guess the btn_4 should be set to red, now if you press the btn_5 and then on the Green button I guess the btn_5 should be green, what happens with btn_4, should keep the color red or should it be reset?

Comment: you clicked btn_1 then red = btn_1 goes red, the other ones kept what already they have set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the setStyleSheet method but you have to keep the reference of the button pressed, and that can be done using the sender method that returns the object that emitted the signal.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent=nullptr):
        QMainWindow(parent),
        current_button(nullptr)
    {
        QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
        setCentralWidget(widget);
        QHBoxLayout *hlay = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
        QVBoxLayout *number_lay = new QVBoxLayout;
        QVBoxLayout *color_lay = new QVBoxLayout;
        hlay->addLayout(number_lay);
        hlay->addLayout(color_lay);

        for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(QString("btn_%1").arg(i+1));
            connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::number_clicked);
            number_lay->addWidget(button);
        }
        color_lay->addStretch();
        for(const QString & colorname: {"Red", "Green", "Blue"}){
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(colorname);
            connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::color_clicked);
            color_lay->addWidget(button);
            button->setProperty("color", colorname.toLower());
            button->setStyleSheet(QString("background-color: %1").arg(colorname));
        }
        color_lay->addStretch();
    }
private slots:
    void number_clicked(){
        current_button = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(sender());
    }
    void color_clicked(){
        if(current_button){
            QString colorname = sender()->property("color").toString();
            current_button->setStyleSheet(QString("background-color: %1").arg(colorname));
        }
    }
private:
    QPushButton *current_button;
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the first button, get its name using the method `objectName()`, then when you need to change the style, just specify in the method

`setStyleSheet(QString(QPushButton#) + button->objectName() + QString("{ ... }");`

I can write the example-program, but I do not fully understand what you want